# Dificuldade em mesclar colunas sequenciais em um DataFrame com Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Possuo dois datas frames, os dois possuem exatamente o mesmo índice, a diferença é que um possui as colunas 'semana 9' até 'semana 30', e o outro possui as colunas 'semana 31' até 'semana 53'.

Até o momento eu utilizei o seguinte código porém não funcionou

```
import pandas as pd

parte1 = pd.read_csv("parte1.csv", encoding = "utf-8", delimiter = ";")
parte2 = pd.read_csv("parte2.csv", encoding = "utf-8", delimiter = ";")

parte3 = pd.merge(parte1, parte2, how = "left")
parte3.to_csv("dados_mesclados_.csv", encoding = "utf-8", sep = ";")
```

O que ocorreu é que a única coisa que foi mesclada foram os títulos das colunas, ou seja, um arquivo foi gerado contendo os headers 'semana 9' até 'semana 53', porém os dados só estão preenchidos referentes a parte1 (semana 9 até a 30).
Fiz outros testes utilizando no lugar do parâmetro 'left' os parâmetros inner, outer e right. O que mais se aproximou do resultado que desejo foi o parâmetro left.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o **concat** do **pandas**, passando os data frames e o eixo das colunas:

```
parte3 = pd.concat([parte1, parte2], axis=1)
```

Comment: O ordenamento funcionou, porém esqueci de comentar mas o arquivo contém colunas em comum de identificação e entre a transição das semanas as colunas de identificação, que são exatamente iguais em ambos os arquivos, se repetiram. Teria como parametrizar uma exceção dentro da função concat para concatenar apenas colunas específicas?

Comment: @standardmarcelo nesse caso talvez o merge resolva seu problema: `parte3 = pd.merge(parte1, parte2, how='inner')`